# Telerik RadFileExplorer modify SaveAs method

Tags: c#, telerik, radfileexplorer

Is their a way i can debug or modify SaveAs method of Telerik RadFileExplorer.
    I am implementing a functionality for Upload on local disk and Object Storage.

```
    Local disk expects path as "C:\\Test\\File.txt" - It works fine
    Object Storage expects path as "Test\\File.txt" - It does not work fine

As i am using telerik Radfileexplorer i dont have control on upload/Saveas method what i guess internally it must be using for upload. How to get hold of it ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way and the best place to do this is inside the FileBrowserContentProvider's StoreFile method. In your case I recommend you to subclass the default provide which ships with radFileExplorer - Telerik.Web.UI.Widgets.FileSystemContentProvider and override its StoreFile method in order to achieve the desired result:

```
public override string StoreFile(UploadedFile file, string path, string name, params string[] arguments)
{
    return base.StoreFile(file, path, name, arguments);
}
```

Please note that you need to return the virtual path of the currently saved file. Then you can set the new provider to the RadFileExplorer control.

You can find more information at
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/fileexplorer/server-side-programming/use-custom-filebrowsercontentprovider
and 
https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/details/use-radfileexplorer-with-physical-and-shared-folder-s-paths